# Get unique values from all lists (Python API Requests)

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, data-structures, python-requests

I am trying to get unique values from the all lists titled "DataClasses" from an API request. With my code it only prints the first list titled "DataClasses" but there are at least 40 other lists called that.

I am confused on how to get all of the lists titled "DataClasses" if I don't know how many times it will be listed on an API request.

```
import requests
import json
import time
import re

with open('dataclasstest2.txt', 'r') as f:
    emails = [line.strip() for line in f]
def main():
    for name in emails:
        url = 'https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/' + name
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'dataclasses.py'
            'Accept: application/vnd.haveibeenpwned.v2+json'
        }
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        if r.status_code == 200:
            data = r.json()[0].get('DataClasses')
            print(name + ":" + ', '.join(data))            
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the output I am getting:

test@example.com:Email addresses, IP addresses, Names, Passwords

Comment: `data = r.json()[0].get('DataClasses')`  <-- You're selecting only the first entry, iterate over the returned JSON list to get `DataClasses` for each.

Comment: @zwer That's what I'm trying to do but for some reason when I do data = r.json()[ ].get('DataClasses') to store all the data it says invalid syntax.

Comment: You need to iterate over the list (i.e. `for data in r.json(): ...`) and then select the `DataClasses` entry for each (i.e. `data['DataClasses']`) to access the actual elements. Read more on [`Lists`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), [`Dictionaries`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [`Control Flow Tools`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) to see how everything ties together.